# MS project plan for part time worker

Tags: ms-project-2010

I am new to MPP. I am trying to plan for a scenario where 2 part time workers are there in my project who work 4 hrs a day for Mon-Wed. I am able to plan if the part time worker works Mon-Fri then I can change max unit for the resource to 50%. As they work only for 3 days then I am really facing difficult to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the working time for the resource. See MS help here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-a-unique-schedule-for-a-specific-resource-ab816ff2-f39d-43b7-b143-ab36d03baaad

Quote from that page:

-Click Project > Properties > Change Working Time.

-Choose a resource from the For calendar list.

-Choose the right Base calendar for the resource.

-If the working times in the calendar aren't quite right for this resource, click the Work Weeks tab, and then click Details.

You may want to try setting your working days/time for these two resources to Mon-Wed, 9AM-1PM to get the 50% for three days. Or just set the three days and try to allocate them at 50%. One may work better than the other.